# Error: 'Item' does not implement interface member 'IUsable.Use(Character)'

Tags: c#

I keep getting an error at the class definition.  I am not sure how to fix this, does anyone have any suggestions?

I think this issue may be causing more errors later on in my code.
The error message is:

> 'Item' does not implement interface member 'IUsable.Use(Character)'

```
abstract class Item : IUsable
{
    public string strEffect;
    public int intEffect = 20;
    public string description;

    public Item ()
    {
        strEffect = "poison";
        intEffect = -10;
        description = "The character will continuously lose 10 health until healed.";
    }

    public string StrEffect
    {
        get { return strEffect; }
        set { strEffect = value; }
    }

    public int IntEffect
    {
        get { return intEffect; }
        set { intEffect = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return description; }
        set { description = value; }
    }

    abstract public void Use();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you need to have a function `Use()` that accepts one `Char` parameter which is defined by the `IUsable` inteface

```
public virtual void Use(Char c) ;
```

Since Item is an abstract class, this `Use` method can be defined with no body. Any non-abstract derived class must override it with a method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are inheriting from an `IUsable` interface, you are going to be required to implement the properties and members that it contains as they are defined.

Although you have the `Use()` method defined within your class, it doesn't accept a parameter and the error message explicitly states it should accept a character (i.e. `Use(Character)`) as seen below :

```
public virtual void Use(Character character);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the exact functions that sit in the interface(with the same number of input params)

So in your case, the interface has a method as follows:

**Interface**

```
interface IUsable
{
    // interface other members and the one this error is about
    public virtual void Use(Char c);
}
```

**Abstract Class**

```
abstract class Item: IUsable
{
   public abstract void Use(Char c);
}
```

You will need to implement it in your abstract class as well. 
You can brush-up some of your [basics here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664595(v=vs.71).aspx).